# What is the comprehension expression in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a few questions buzzing in my head about the comprehension expression:

- What is the data structure which it defines?
- Was it adapted from some other language?
- Where is it used in AngularJS? Does this API exist for select elements only?

[From the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect):

> ngOptions - comprehension_expression - in one of the following forms:
>
> for array data sources:
>
> - label for value in array
> - select as label for value in array
> - label group by group for value in array
> - select as label group by group for value in array track by trackexpr
>
> for object data sources:
>
> - label for (key , value) in object
> - select as label for (key , value) in object
> - label group by group for (key, value) in object
> - select as label group by group for (key, value) in object

Comment: "Does this API exist for select elements only?" Its used in [Angular UI Bootstrap's Typeahead directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) as well (which is very `select`'y)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Comprehension expression is just a string formatted in a special way to be recognized by `select` directive.

There's no magic behind it, just several formats of it because there are quite a few ways to process and represent your collection (data structure of your model, item/item property selection as scope's model, some other options regarding labels, grouping etc.). When you consider all these options it is not that strange for allowing complex expressions.

Let's say you have such code:

```
<select
  ng-model="color"
  ng-options="c.name group by c.shade for c in colors"></select>
```

In order to ditch the comprehension expression and use attributes, you would write something like this:

```
<select
  ng-model="color"
  ng-data-type="object"
  ng-data="colors"
  ng-select="c"
  ng-label="c.name"
  ng-group-by="c.shade"></select>
```

The attribute approach might get ugly once you expand your API. Besides, with comprehension expression it's much easier to use filters.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I'll wait for other answers and accept in a couple of days.

Comment: Very interesting... I'm really curious where you found the alternate syntax to ng-options (in your second example above). I can't find any documentation for it, did you read the source to discover them?

Comment: There's no such syntax in official docs, because I created it for the sake of example, what would it take to write `selects` without comprehension expression. However it would not take much effort to write a wrapper directive around `select` that would use attributes as input and would produce comprehension expression for the `select` as the output.

Answer (score 3):

While in one way it's true to say that a "comprehension_expression" is "just a string" as package says, on the other hand, source code is just a string. Programming languages are just strings.

A SQL SELECT statement

– which could very well be part of the inspiration for the syntax and features of the "comprehension_expression" (but it's not obvious that it is, because it's not mentioned in the docs– perhaps if I dug into some developer conversations I might be able to find out) –

is just a string.

Sure they're just strings, but they have structure, which relates to the problem they are trying to solve. And the question is, is the structure adequately described? Is its pattern, how it relates to the problem at hand, made clear? Is its relationship to other structures that other people have designed apparent?

While the "comprehension_expression" is just a string, on the other hand, its complexity almost comes to it being a sort of sub-language in its own right.

But the way it is portrayed in the docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) does reflect the attitude that it is "just a string with some formatting". It is tucked away in the documentation for ng-options as the type of the ng-options directive. To some extent, it is not an entity in its own right, it is a second-class citizen.

The way the different formats are listed can give one a strange feeling, like it's sort of ad-hoc, without any pattern relating the different possible formats (although there is a pattern if you look closely). Without a formal grammar with a regular structure, it makes you wonder if they really covered all the possible options. Compared to, say, the MySQL documentation for the SQL SELECT statement: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Obviously such formal syntax can be quite intimidating and is maybe not necessary for the case of the "comprehension_expression", on the other hand it can be reassuring to know it is precisely defined.

I suspect the asker of the question was somewhat unsettled by how casually the "comprehension_expression" was mentioned in the docs; it can seem like a sort of floating, ghost-like entity, just mentioned briefly but not given its own page etc.

It might be worth it having its own page, being treated as an entity in its own right, because then that invites discussion as to the design of this "sub-language". How did it come about? What are the reasons for the different features of the "sub-language"? Which features, and thus syntaxes, conflict with each other? Why can this feature be used together with that feature but not another feature? Are there inspirations from e.g. SQL, in the design of this "sub-language"?

Otherwise it seems to be an invention out of the blue, unrelated to other DSLs of its kind.

In a blog post on ng-options,
https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs/
Mr. Shidhin links to a little discussion
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/4EDe8xIbjLU

Where just this issue is discussed. "Matt Hughes" also expresses the opinion that "Seems like a lot of additional complexity for one directive."

Perhaps this is not that big a deal. I just wanted to put it out there though.